# How do I connect a Windows NT 4.0 pc to a Windows 11 pc serially via USB to RS-232 cable?

Tags: hyperterminal, windows-nt-4

I have been trying to connect two PCs serially via a USB to RS 232 cable for the past week. One PC is running on Windows NT 4.0 with no floppy disk drive nor LAN cable. The other PC is a normal PC running on Windows 11. I have been searching in almost every other website for this but to no avail. Please help...

Note: I have already tried hyperterminal which is inbuild in windows NT and downloaded the same for windows 11.

Comment: What sort of cable are you using? You need a null-modem connecting pins 2, 3 & 5 (minimum).

Comment: Best to get the files you need from NT4 on a USB key that you can read on Windows 11.

Comment: @spikey_richie I am using a HL-340 USB serial port (COM) USB to RS232 USB Nine Serial Line Support Windows 7-64 which is available in Amazon. The PC which is having Windows NT 4.0 has a RS-232 male port.

Comment: @John Can you please elaborate, do you mean an USB drive? I am in an organisation where all USBs are removed from our systems except in my personal PC i.e. the one with the windows 11 installed. The one where windows NT4 is loaded does not have any USB connections.

Comment: NT4 Workstation can use USB Flash drives. If the computer does not have a USB port then you will need a null cable of some sort.

Comment: @John The PC having windows NT already have a male RS-232, can't I just connect the female RS232 lead of  HL-340 USB serial port (COM) USB to RS232 USB Nine Serial Line to the male lead?

Comment: NT4 is so ancient that the way you are trying to connect may possibly never work. If you need data from it, bus connect a CD-Writer and get data that way.  Even consider a floppy drive. You can probably use a USB floppy drive on Windows 11. You could on WIN10.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the hard drive, and put in the other computer.  IDE to USB exist if you really need that.

Comment: @cybernard Not possible, as the windows NT 4 system is integrated to a device. I just want for it to transfer a .txt file to the windows 11 PC.